# History.js firing two requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

On this page: http://www.kastenreus.nl/onze-kasten/ we have the filters down the left hand side, we are having a problem with the link filters under Verfijn uw wensen, if you watch the console you can see it is firing 2 requests, the first one is what the content is loading in from, when it is the second we actually need.

This is the click binded event:

```
jQuery(".codenegar_product_filter_wrap ul li a").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    if($this.attr("data-key") == "cat" && $this.attr("data-widget") == "cat" ){
        $this.closest("li").siblings().removeClass("codenegar_applied_filter chosen");
    }
    $this.closest("li").toggleClass("codenegar_applied_filter chosen");
    var widget = $this.attr("data-widget");
    var type = $this.attr("data-type");
    var key = $this.attr("data-key");
    var value = $this.attr("data-value");

    var new_key = widget + "_" + key; // key for url
    var current_value = codenegar_get_parameter(new_key);
    //current_value += "," + value;
    if(current_value != "" && new_key != "cat_cat"){
        current_value = current_value.split(",");
    }else{
        current_value =[];
    }
    var value_index = jQuery.inArray(value, current_value);
    if(value_index > -1){  // if duplicated remove item to have toggle effect
        current_value.splice(value_index, 1);
    }else{
        current_value.push(value);
    }
    //current_value = jQuery.unique(current_value);
    new_value = current_value.join(",");
    if(new_key == "cat_cat" && codenegar_get_parameter("cat_cat") == new_value){
        new_value = ""; // toggle effect
    }
    codenegar_wcpf_add_parameter(widget, type, key, new_value);
});
```

This is the code of codenegar_wcpf_add_parameter

```
function codenegar_wcpf_add_parameter(widget, type, key, value){
    var state = History.getState();
    var current_url = state.cleanUrl;
    var new_url = "";
    var new_key = widget + "_" + key;
    if(new_key=='orderby_orderby') new_key = 'orderby'; // use native WooCommerce ordering
    new_url = codenegar_addParameter(current_url, "cnpf", "1", true); // at first
    new_url = codenegar_addParameter(new_url, "cnep", "0"); // disable paging: shows first page
    new_url = codenegar_addParameter(new_url, new_key, value);
    // some themes bring shop at home, so make it possible to filter products at home
    if((document.URL==codenegar_wcpf_config.home_url) || (document.URL==codenegar_wcpf_config.home_url+"/")){
        new_url = codenegar_addParameter(new_url, "post_type", "product");
    }
    if(codenegar_page_title.length==0){
        codenegar_page_title = jQuery("title").text();
    }
    History.pushState({state:1}, codenegar_page_title, new_url);
}
```

And this is the function that catches the statechange and loads the content:

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event

    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        //History.log(State);
        var $wrap = jQuery("span.codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper");
        if($wrap.length==0){
            // theme is not standard an missing WooCommerce actions/hooks
            $wrap = jQuery("ul.products");
        }
        var height = $wrap.css("height");
        $wrap.hide().html('<div id="codenegar_ajax_loader"> <img src="' + codenegar_wcpf_config.loader_img + '" class="codenegar-ajax-loader"/> </div>')
                .css("height", height).fadeIn();

        if (typeof wcsl_before_ajax == 'function') {
          wcsl_before_ajax();
        }
        // now load filtered products
                jQuery.get(decodeURI(State.cleanUrl), function(data) {
                    //console.log(data);
            var $data = jQuery(data);
            var shop_loop = jQuery('div.product-loop',jQuery(data));
            var shop_ul = $data.find('ul.products');
            if(shop_loop.length>0){
                $wrap.hide().html(shop_loop).fadeIn();
            }else if(shop_ul.length>0){
                $wrap.hide().html(shop_ul).fadeIn();
            }else{
                if(codenegar_wcpf_config.display_no_products_message=='yes'){
                    $wrap.hide().html(codenegar_wcpf_config.no_products_message).fadeIn();
                }
            }
            if($data.find('.codenegar-shop-loop-wrapper').children(".codenegar-shop-pagination-wrapper").length==0){
                jQuery(".codenegar-shop-pagination-wrapper").hide().html($data.find(".codenegar-shop-pagination-wrapper")).fadeIn();
            }

            var selected_cat = 0;
            var url = State.cleanUrl;
            var last_parameter = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('&') + 1);
            if(last_parameter.length>0 && last_parameter.indexOf("=")>-1){
                last_parameter = last_parameter.split("=");
                if(last_parameter.length == 2 && last_parameter[0]== "cat_cat"){
                    selected_cat = last_parameter[1];
                }
            }
            if(parseInt(selected_cat)>0 || selected_cat=="0"){
                var clicked_widget = jQuery('.codenegar_product_filter_wrap ul li a[data-value='+ selected_cat +']').closest(".codenegar_product_filter_wrap");
                var updated_widget = $data.find('.codenegar_product_filter_wrap ul li a[data-old-value='+ selected_cat +']').closest(".codenegar_product_filter_wrap").children();
                if(updated_widget.length>0){
                    clicked_widget.hide().html(updated_widget).fadeIn();
                }
            }

            // custom are update
                        if (typeof wcsl_on_update == 'function') {
              var areas = wcsl_on_update();
              var length = areas.length;
              for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
                var element = areas[i];
                // if(element.length==0){
                    // continue;
                // }
                var updated_area = $data.find(element);
                if(updated_area.length>0){
                jQuery(element).hide().html(updated_area).fadeIn();
              }else{
                jQuery(element).hide().html("");
              }
            }
            }

        }).done(function() {
            if (typeof wcsl_ajax_done == 'function') {
              wcsl_ajax_done();
            }
            })
          .fail(function() {
            if (typeof wcsl_ajax_fail == 'function') {
              wcsl_ajax_fail();
            }
            //if(codenegar_wcpf_config.display_no_products_message=='yes'){
                $wrap.hide().html(codenegar_wcpf_config.no_products_message).fadeIn();
            //}
           })
         .always(function() {
            if (typeof wcsl_after_ajax == 'function') {
              wcsl_after_ajax();
            }
           });;
    });

})(window);
```